# Align predefined text to left and display string aligned to the right. Java

Tags: java, eclipse, alignment, printf, println

In Java, how do I use print or printf to have A line of text, that has the first output as "Character Name:" (which is aligned to the left by default) and then show a string value (char1) to be aligned to the right of the screen, or aligned to the right of a column? ie:

```
   Character Name:                      char1

   Character Value:                 charValue
```

ps.  I am using eclipse if that helps.

Comment: Read about field width in the [documentation of the `Formatter` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), which is what `printf` uses for formatting.

Comment: Sorry for my answer I thought this was c because of the printf!

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.format("Character Name: %25s", x);
System.out.format("Character Value: %24s", y);
```

You will have to mess around with the formatting to decide how many spaces you'll have to include in between; it will depend on the length of the left justified word. But using a format `%s` will right justify by default, or left justify if you use `%-s`. The number between `%` & `s` is the amount of spaces in between.

Comment: Thanks for that, but using the `%25s` example the value of char1 and charValue will vary greatly in length, which would throw that out of consideration for the answer, as I specifically want the output of the string to be right aligned.  I tried use %s by itself and that didn't right align.

Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You'll need to play around with the formatting so that they all match up, I don't think there's a way to do it automatically. Unless for example you pick an amount of spaces and add/take away from that amount based on the length of the first word. For example, in my solution there is 17 characters between the first " and the % sign (from `'C'` to `' '`) in the first line. In the second line there is 18 because `Value` is one letter longer. So in the second line I use `%24s`. You could write a quick script to calculate this for you.